# What's the name of this gold chain designed very flexible like a spring

Tags: jewelry

There is this gold chain with these specs:

- Designed like flexible springs.
- Looks enormous but only weighs around 3.66 grams
- It won't break. It won't rupture.

  - But it could get damaged by getting distorted in shape.
- It has a higher price for manual labor.

## Question

What's the name of this chain design? Are there any technical details about it?

[image: Slide]

Comment: Woven Gold Chain?

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm obsessed with how interesting it is woven. Is there any documentation on how it's made?

Comment: Mesh chain is crafted of very fine wire woven to produce chain that has a fluid, fabric-like flexibility.

Comment: What is manual labor  for ? Chains like this are produced on automated equipment . Very impressive to watch.

Comment: @blacksmith37 You're right. Manufacturing should be automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a Mesh Woven Braided Chain.